# i am trying to replace each column values which contain 1's in an array with alphabets using c#, doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#

My array looks like this:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
0  0  1  1
0  1  0  1
```

so in the above i need to replace c1 column values with a, c2 column values with b, c3 column values with c 
This is the code i have used but still displays the entire file with the changes not being implemented:

```
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\as.csv");
        for (var i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var lineSplit = lines[i].Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            lineSplit[0] = lineSplit[0].Equals("1") ? "a" : lineSplit[0];

            lineSplit[1] = lineSplit[1].Equals("1") ? "b" : lineSplit[1];
            lineSplit[2] = lineSplit[2].Equals("1") ? "c" : lineSplit[2];
            Console.WriteLine(lineSplit[0]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you share the code you already tried?

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"d/tet.csv")))
           {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

           foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you.

```
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            item.c1 = item.c1.Equals("1") ? "a" : item.c1;
            item.c2 = item.c2.Equals("1") ? "b" : item.c2;
            item.c3 = item.c3.Equals("1") ? "c" : item.c3;  
            item.c4 = item.c4.Equals("1") ? "d" : item.c4;  
        }
```

Hope I understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input , the problem im having is i have copied the csv file into a list but when i try to display column headers are not visible , here is my code

Comment: List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"d/tet.csv")))
           {
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

           foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();